# API for iOS registered protocol handlers

Tags: ios, ruby

Is there an API where I can check if a registered iOS protocol handler exists or not? I'm looking to figure out if a few protocol handlers that were given to me are valid.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Not entirely sure I understand what you're asking :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about application URL schemes, you can use:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:<#(NSURL *)#>]
```

which will return `YES` if there is an app that can open the URL scheme or `NO` if there isn't.